# Efficient way of comparing objects from two NSArrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch

I have two arrays, one has 1400 records and one has 450.  The larger array is a list of 'search terms' for drugs with a corresponding drug id.  The second array contains the 'drug objects' themselves with around 15 fields containing various information about the drug.

What I need is a new array of 'search term objects' that is effectively the search term array where all search terms have been replaced by drugs (but the search term has been added to the object).

What I have done so far is to add another property (searchTerm) to my  drug object.  I loop through the search terms array and then for each search term I loop through the drug objects array and when I find a matching DrugID I create a new instance of the drug object copying all of the information from the original drug object and populating the searchTerm from the search term array.

This doesn't seem efficient at all and takes over 600,000 iterations to fully populate the new array, this takes around 1 minute.

```
    FormularyDBManager *formularyDBManagerInstance = [FormularyDBManager new];
    NSArray *searchTermArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[formularyDBManagerInstance getSearchDrugs:@"*" from:@"formulary_searchname" orderBy:@"DrugName"]];

    int counter = 0; // this counter is here purely for testing

    for (NSDictionary *searchDrug in searchTermArray) {

        for (Drug *aDrug in arrayOfDrugs) { // this array is populated in a previous method

            counter ++; 
            NSLog(@"Counter = %i", counter);

            if ([searchDrug[@"DrugID"] isEqualToString:aDrug.drugID]) {

                Drug *currentDrug = [Drug new];

                currentDrug.therapeuticGroup2 = aDrug.therapeuticGroup2;
                currentDrug.use = aDrug.use;
                currentDrug.action = aDrug.action;
                currentDrug.therapeuticGroup1 = aDrug.therapeuticGroup1;
                // more properties.... then the search term is added
                currentDrug.drugName = searchDrug[@"searchTerm"];

                [arrayOfSearchDrugs addObject:currentDrug];

            }

        }

    }

    [_tableViewDrugs reloadData];
```

What is the correct way of doing this?  Thanks.

**Solution** as per  Guillaume's answer below

```
NSArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[formularyDBManagerInstance getSearchDrugs:@"*" from:@"formulary_searchname" orderBy:@"DrugName"]];

DataBaseMananger *dataBaseManagerInstance = [DataBaseMananger new];

for (NSDictionary *searchDrug in resultArray) {

    // get the drug object from the new drugs dictionary where the drugID matches the current item in the returned 'search items' array
    Drug *aDrug = [dictOfDrugs objectForKey:searchDrug[@"DrugID"]];  

    Drug *currentDrug = [Drug new];
    NSMutableArray *columns = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray new];

    currentDrug.therapeuticGroup2 = aDrug.therapeuticGroup2;
    [columns addObject:@"TherapeuticGroup2"];
    [values  addObject:currentDrug.therapeuticGroup2];

    currentDrug.use = aDrug.use;
    [columns addObject:@"Use"];
    [values addObject:currentDrug.use];

    currentDrug.action = aDrug.action;
    [columns addObject:@"Action"];
    [values addObject:currentDrug.action];

    currentDrug.therapeuticGroup1 = aDrug.therapeuticGroup1;
    [columns addObject:@"TherapeuticGroup1"];
    [values addObject:currentDrug.therapeuticGroup1];

    // other properties.....

    currentDrug.searchTerm = searchDrug[@"searchTerm"];
    [columns addObject:@"searchTerm"];
    [values addObject:currentDrug.searchTerm];

    // now add the new 'search term objects' to a database table so they can be retrieved even quicker later on.
    [dataBaseManagerInstance insertToTable:@"formulary_searchDrug" setColumns:columns equals:values];
    [arrayOfSearchDrugs addObject:currentDrug];

}

[_tableViewDrugs reloadData];
```

**update**

Taking the initialisation of the arrays (that get entered into my database import method) out of the loop help massively, not sure why I had them in there really.

The load time for the UITableView that took it's data from the array in question started at 55 seconds, after modifying the code went down to 21 seconds and after taking the array initialisation out of the loop took it down to 10 seconds.

Comment: Sounds like you should use NSSet and it's variants. And you should have a look at [Designing Code for Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/)

Comment: I'm confused why have you put the section marked as `Solution as per Guillaume's answer below` what does this have to do with the question itself. If they have provided you with the correct answer then just mark it as correct don't go adding the solution to your answer. P.S. @vikingosegundo it's been a while since we've had a disagreement so "You can subclass `UIAlertView`" (Jokes)

Comment: Well, now even you can't subclass it anymore. But I dare you to prove me wrong.  @Popeye

Comment: @vikingosegundo hahaha

Comment: @Popeye - Guillaume's answer pointed me in the right direction.  I did have to modify it slightly to work for my purposes, I posted the 'solution' with this modification so that anyone reading the question would know exactly what the answer was in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the drugs in `arrayOfDrugs` have a unique `drugID`, then you can create a map (dictionary) of the drugs indexed by their ID, and ditch the inner loop.

This should make the complexity change from O(n * m) to O(n + m) (`n` being the size of `searchTermArray`, and `m` the size of arrayOfDrugs)*.

This should looks something like:

```
FormularyDBManager *formularyDBManagerInstance = [FormularyDBManager new];
NSArray *searchTermArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[formularyDBManagerInstance getSearchDrugs:@"*" from:@"formulary_searchname" orderBy:@"DrugName"]];

for (NSDictionary *searchDrug in searchTermArray) {

        Drug *aDrug = dictOfDrugs[aDrug.drugID]
        Drug *currentDrug = [Drug new];

        currentDrug.therapeuticGroup2 = aDrug.therapeuticGroup2;
        currentDrug.use = aDrug.use;
        currentDrug.action = aDrug.action;
        currentDrug.therapeuticGroup1 = aDrug.therapeuticGroup1;
        // more properties.... then the search term is added
        currentDrug.drugName = searchDrug[@"searchTerm"];

        [arrayOfSearchDrugs addObject:currentDrug];
    }
}
```

Of course don't forget to change your method creating the `arrayOfDrugs` array to return a dictionary.

** Don't take my word for it on this, it has been years since I last tried to express my code complexity somewhat formally.*

Comment: The returning array returns and array of dictionaries, each dictionary being a row (drug object) in the database.  Do you suggest I return one dictionary with all of the drugs in it?

Comment: Could you be more precise? From you code (`for (Drug *aDrug in arrayOfDrugs)`) it seemed that `arrayOfDrugs` was an `NSArray` filled with `Drug` objects. Isn't it the case?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, you are correct, the arrayOfDrugs is an array of 'Drug' objects.  I was confusing what you were saying with how the arrayOfDrugs was populated in the first place.  So, instead of an array of drugs I could use a dictionary of drugs?

Comment: Yep, I think it's worth a try. Instead of an NSArray, construct a NSDictionary with the key being the `drugID` of each drug object. Then in you loop, instead of iterating through `arrayOfDrugs` you can retrieve each drug in O(1) time from the dict.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense.  I'll change the NSArray to NSDictionary and give it a whirl and report my findings.

Comment: I have implemented this idea and it works like a charm!  Thanks for your help, the process of populating the new array has gone from 55 seconds to 21 seconds.  At the same time I have also decided to store the results in a database and so users will only experience this longer loading of a UITableView on the app's first launch.  This is just the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it worked. However, 21 seconds is still a (very) long time to iterate an array of 1400 elements. It may be the `Drug` object allocation and initialization in the loop. I'd recommend using Instrument's time profiler to measure the culprit if you want to make it faster still. Also, I think this kind of question has it place on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: Yeah I was dissapointed the first time my code ran as I assumed this kind of work is exactly what modern processors do with ease.  In my mind even a sloppy loop in a loop with 600k iteration should be done in seconds but maybe I'm naive.  21 seconds isn't fantastic but still a massive reduction.  I guess the instantiation of the drug object (which has around 25 properties) may be the issue now... good call on the codereview, I may take a look and post a question.

Comment: I think that using a NSDictionary for elements in an array is a very nice way of solving issues like this. Thumbs up :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do if you have to check each object of both arrays and you are expecting more than one results. if you are expecting one result, you can break the loop when it is found. However, if you remove the **NSLog** thing from the loop, it will definitely improve the performance and time taken.

Comment: The NSLog was just there for me to count the iterations and to see how 'fast' the process really was.  It's painful to watch, actually.

Comment: Remove NSLog line and then check the time taken.

Comment: Takes around 55 seconds.  It was just in there for diagnostic reasons and will be deleted when a solution to my query has been found.

Comment: @Ryan In general, you want to measure you algorithms performance without debug logs and on a Release build (to benefit from the -Os compiler flag). But ~1min while in Debug is still way too much for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Just an ideia here, not sure if it will really be an improvement, but what about if you loop the smaller array and use nspredicate to filter the larger one for the drugIDs you need

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"propertyName == %@", @"value"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

In all cases where matching of objects of different types can be reduced to equality of some object of the same time (as in your case the member drugID and the dictionary value for the key "DrugID"), it's fastest to put one set of items into a temporary dictionary with that object as the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain `O(n), n = number of drugs` by using set arithmetics with `NS(Mutable)Set`.

My example will map search terms to list of drugs that contains that search term in an dictionary.

The main operation her is intersecting one set with another.

Let's get started:

You didn't provide a class for Drug, so I created my own.
As I have no idea about drugs, I am just using random numbers as properties. I will make these accessible through an method, that will return a set to perform the intersection.

```
@interface Drug : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f3;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f4;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f5;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f6;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f7;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f8;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f9;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f10;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f11;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f12;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f13;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f14;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *f15;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSSet *drugProperties;
@end


static unsigned int numberOfSearchTerms = 14000;
static unsigned int numberOfDrugs = 450;
@implementation Drug

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.f1 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f2 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f3 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f4 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f5 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f6 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f7 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f8 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f9 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f10 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f11 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f12 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f13 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f14 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
        self.f15 = @(arc4random_uniform(numberOfSearchTerms) +1);
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSSet *)drugProperties
{
    return [NSSet setWithArray:@[_f1, _f2, _f3, _f4, _f5, _f6, _f7,_f8, _f9, _f10, _f11, _f12, _f13, _f14, _f15]];
}

@end
```

The search terms in my example are numbers as-well.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    for (int x = 0; x<5; ++x) {
        NSMutableDictionary *searchTermDrugMapping =[@{} mutableCopy];
        NSMutableSet *searchTerms = [NSMutableSet set];

        for(NSUInteger i = 1; i< numberOfSearchTerms+1; ++i){
            //                [searchTerms addObject:[[SeachrTermSetWrapper alloc] initWithSearchTerm:@(i)]];
            [searchTerms addObject:@(i)];
            searchTermDrugMapping[@(i)] = [@[] mutableCopy];

        }

        NSMutableArray *drugs = [@[] mutableCopy];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i< (numberOfDrugs << x) ; ++i) {
            [drugs addObject: [[Drug alloc] init]];
        }

        NSTimeInterval start = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        for (Drug *d in drugs) {
            NSMutableSet *dp = [d.drugProperties mutableCopy];
            [dp intersectSet:searchTerms];
            [dp enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                [searchTermDrugMapping[obj] addObject:d];
            }];
        }
        NSTimeInterval stop = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        //NSLog(@"%@", searchTermDrugMapping);

        NSLog(@"%u \t\t%f",(numberOfDrugs << x), stop -start);
    }


    return YES;
}
```

output (# of drugs, time in sec) iOS 8.1 iPhone 5s

```
450         0.015040
900         0.027976
1800        0.057547
3600        0.117761
7200        0.235752
```

Doubling the number of drugs doubles the time -> linear behaviour -> `O(n)`

That was quite easy. But it can become more complicated. To do Set operation like that among you need Equality of the objects in the different set. [NSHipster has a great article about it](http://nshipster.com/equality/). But what id I have objects of different Kind. That is easy: write Classes that wrap these objects and make them accept each other as equal. Wrap your real objectsnin instances of them and put them into the set.

Answer (score -4):

you can use containsObject method

ex:

```
for (NSDictionary *checkData1 in  objects) {

      if (![objects2 containsObject:checkData1]) {

     }
}
```

like this ....

Comment: From the doc `containsObject`: "This method determines whether anObject is present in the array by sending an isEqual: message to each of the array’s objects". So this will do exactly the same as @Ryan performance-wise, but calling `isEqual` instead of comparing IDs. So if `isEqual` is not implemented in `Drug`, this will do a pointer comparison and most likely fail.